# FileNotFoundError rendering decision tree with CHAID

Tags: python, decision-tree

I used the following code to get the decision tree of CHAID

```
independent_variable_columns = ['gender', 'grade', 'no_renewals', 'complaint_count']
dep_variable = 'switch'
tree = Tree.from_pandas_df(
    df,
    dict(zip(independent_variable_columns, ['nominal'] * 38)),
    dep_variable,
    max_depth=2
)
tree.to_tree()
tree.render()
```

but I am getting the following error

```
  File "C:\Users\data\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\CHAID\graph.py", line 93, in <listcomp>
    [os.remove(file) for file in self.files]
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/tmp/157840175993116164207458496094.png'
```

Comment: Is this https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID perhaps? Or is it a different library?

Comment: Must be, because there is [a confirmed bug report for a similar error](https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID/issues/97) in the repository. And presumably you filed the [other issue](https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID/issues/99)?

Comment: The maintainer is asking for additional information there, you can probably get them to fix the issue faster if you provided that information yourself.

Comment: Yes this is https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID library only

Answer (score 1):

That specific library is not implementing best practices when it comes to generating filenames and handling temporary files. That makes their code break, in a variety of ways, on Windows.

I've left a comment on a [similar issue with the same root cause](https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID/issues/97), proposing changes to fix these issues.

You can fix this locally by running this code:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

import plotly.io as pio
import colorlover as cl
from graphviz import Digraph

from CHAID import graph

def Graph_render(self, path, view):
    if path is None:
        path = os.path.join("trees", f"{datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}.gv")
    with TemporaryDirectory() as self.tempdir:
        g = Digraph(
            format="png",
            graph_attr={"splines": "ortho"},
            node_attr={"shape": "plaintext", "labelloc": "b"},
        )
        for node in self.tree:
            image = self.bar_chart(node)
            g.node(str(node.node_id), image=image)
            if node.parent is not None:
                edge_label = f"     ({', '.join(map(str, node.choices))})     \n ")
                g.edge(str(node.parent), str(node.node_id), xlabel=edge_label)

        g.render(path, view=view)

def Graph_bar_chart(self, node):
    fig = {
        "data": [
            {
                "values": list(node.members.values()),
                "labels": list(node.members),
                "showlegend": node.node_id == 0,
                "domain": {"x": [0, 1], "y": [0.4, 1.0]},
                "hole": 0.4,
                "type": "pie",
                "marker_colors": cl.scales["5"]["qual"]["Set1"],
            },
        ],
        "layout": {
            "margin_t": 50,
            "annotations": [{"font_size": 18, "x": 0.5, "y": 0.5}, {"y": [0, 0.2]}],
        },
    }

    if not node.is_terminal:
        p = None if node.p is None else format(node.p, ".5f")
        score = None if node.score is None else format(node.score, ".2f")
        self.append_table(fig, [p, score, node.split.column])

    filename = os.path.join(self.tempdir, f"node-{node.node_id}.png")
    pio.write_image(fig, file=filename, format="png")
    return filename

graph.Graph.render = Graph_render
graph.Graph.bar_chart = Graph_bar_chart
```

The above is a refactor of two methods from the `Graph` class in that library, switching to using `tempdir.TemporaryDirectory()` to handle temporary files, and cleaning up how filenames are generated. I also took the liberty to clean up some minor issues in the code.

I've turned this into a [pull request to update the project itself](https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID/pull/100).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I m getting the following error.PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\RANJIT~1.PS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpmbv62ah1\\tmp4ld852us.png'

Comment: I deleted the temp files and done restart but still the same. please help me in fixing this.

Comment: @ran_search: I've synched my answer with the updated pull request; using `mkstemp()` for the image files was overkill and causing issues on Windows.

Comment: How do I pass dot file originated from CHAID decision tree to create tree chart with the following format

Comment: @ran_search that’s an entirely different question, and perhaps warrants a different post. CHAID outputs a [Graphviz *dot* file](https://www.graphviz.org/), with images for each node to visualise the distribution of values (both as a pie chart and a table). The images themselves are deleted again after incorporating them into the PNG rendering of the graph, so the output text file itself is rather useless. If you want to create a different graph, better to use the data from the tree itself. I have never done that and don’t have time now to figure that out.

Comment: @ran_search ah, you followed up on GitHub. This is getting to be very confusing, going back and forth between different locations. You can’t generate the graph because the images used are deleted now. The problem seems to be that you have independent variables with numeric values, whereas the original code assumed them to be strings. Just replace `node.choices` in `', '.join(node.choices)` with `map(str, node.choices)`, so it reads `', '.join(map(str, node.choices))`