# Error while importing the python CHAID package - Solved

Tags: python, import, python-import, decision-tree

I have installed python CHAID Package from here [CHAID Package](https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID), I am trying to import CHAID into my notebook . But I am getting a syntax error when I import the package

```
from CHAID import Tree
```

error message:

```
 File "C:\...\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\CHAID\graph.py", line 75
    file = 'C:\...\Documents\Python Scripts\CHAID\temp\' + ("%.20f" % time.time()).replace('.', '') + '.png'


    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I found this link here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629061/filenotfounderror-rendering-decision-tree-with-chaid) but the solution there didn't worked for me since I cannot even import Chaid library. what should I do to make it work? thx

**Edit**
The most recent CHAID version doesn't use `line 75 of graph.py` method anymore, so if upgrade to version 5.3.0 or higher will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the package was written with and intended for Python 2.x, while you use Python 3.x.

Comment: according to the GitHub page the package was written with Python 3.x and actually developer don't encourage the use of pyhton 2.x

Answer (score -1):

Add `r` to your string literals, e.g.

```py
file = r'C:\...\Documents\Python Scripts\CHAID\temp\'
```

or use double backslashes:

```py
file = 'C:\\...\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\CHAID\\temp\\'
```